# Evalutate $\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{3}x^4}}$

Tags: integration

How to integrate
$$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{3}x^4}}$$
Mathematica found
$$\ln x-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{3}x^4}\right)$$
but I can't find a method to arrive at this solution.

Comment: where have you stucked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $u=\sqrt{1-(4/3)x^4}$, $u^2=1-(4/3)x^4$, $2u\,du=-(16/3)x^3\,dx$, together with $dx/x=x^3\,dx/x^4$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $ x^2 = \frac{\sqrt{3}\sin y}{2} $ and hence the integral is equivalent to $$\begin{align*} \displaystyle \int \frac{\cos y}{2\sin y \cos y} &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\ln(1 - \cos y) - \ln \sin y\right) + C\\&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\ln\left(1 - \sqrt{1 - \frac{4}{3}x^4}\right) - \ln\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt3}x^2\right)\right) + C \\&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - \frac{4}{3}x^4}}{x^2}\right)\right) + C - \frac{1}{2}\ln \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \\&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\ln\left(\frac{\frac{4}{3}x^4}{x^2\left(1 + \sqrt{1 - \frac{4}{3}x^4}\right)}\right)\right) + C - \frac{1}{2}\ln \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \\&=\ln x - \frac{1}{2}\ln\left(1 + \sqrt{1 - \frac{4}{3}x^4}\right) + C + \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}  \end{align*}$$